# Cannot assign "'7'": "Appointment.your_service" must be a "Service" instance

Tags: python, django

I'm working on a project "Beauty Parlour Management System" and I got this error (Cannot assign "'7'": "Appointment.your_service" must be a "Service" instance.) anyone here can help me, please.

When I am filling a book appointment form then I got this error.

models.py

```
class Service(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    price = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='uploads/productImg')

class Appointment(models.Model):
    your_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    your_phone = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    your_email = models.EmailField(max_length=200)
    your_service = models.ForeignKey('Service', on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)
    your_date = models.DateField()
```

views.py

```
def appointments(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render(request, 'core/bookappointment.html')
    else:   
        your_name = request.POST.get('your-name')
        your_phone = request.POST.get('your-phone')
        your_email = request.POST.get('your-email')
        your_service = request.POST.get('your-service')
        your_date = request.POST.get('your-date')
    
        details = Appointment(
            your_name = your_name, 
            your_phone = your_phone, 
            your_email = your_email, 
            your_service = your_service, 
            your_date = your_date)
        details.save()
        return render(request, 'core/appointments.html')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create this by assigining the method to `your_service_id` field, if you work with `your_service`, it should be a `Service` object:

```
details = Appointment.objects.create(
    your_name=your_name, 
    your_phone=your_phone, 
    your_email=your_email, 
    your_service_id=your_service,
    your_date=your_date
)
```

That being said, it is usually better to validate, clean, and save the data with a `ModelForm`, not manually.

---

> **Note**: In case of a successful POST request, you should make a [**`redirect`**
> [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect)
> to implement the [*Post/Redirect/Get* pattern [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).
> This avoids that you make the same POST request when the user refreshes the
> browser.

Answer (score 0):

```
def appointments(request,pk):
    record = get_object_or_404(Service,pk=pk)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        
        form = appointmentsForm(request.POST,request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            appointment= form.save(commit=False)
            appointment.your_service = record
            appointment.save()
            return render(request, 'core/bookappointment.html')
    else:   
        
        return render(request, 'core/appointments.html')
```